# Get Folders opened - PowerShell script in python syntax

Tags: python, powershell, pywin32

I have the following powershell script that brings me the path of the open folders in windows

```
$app = New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application'
$app.Windows() | Select-Object LocationURL
```

And I want to do the same thing in python, but the `Select-Object LocationURL` part I can't do it

```
from win32com import client
shell = client.Dispatch("Shell.Application")
shell.Windows()
```

How to replicate `$app.Windows() | Select-Object LocationURL` in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate `shell.Windows()` and use the `LocationURL` attribute, like so:

```py
from win32com import client

shell = client.Dispatch("Shell.Application")
for window in shell.Windows():
    print(window.LocationURL)
```

Output:

```
file:///C:/Users/Admin/Downloads
file:///C:/Stuff
```

Comment: Now that you mention it, it's obvious haha thank you very much.